# how to create sign-in and sign-up form & create a test for it backend in Java and frontend js?

Tags: java

I would like to learn, how can I make a project that has this function. (sign-in and sign-up)
These are the classes that I have so far.

this is the entity i have also the class User

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id" ,nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name" )
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "last_name" )
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "Email" )
    private String email;

    protected UserEntity() {

    }

    public UserEntity( String firstname, String lastname, String email) {

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;


    }
```

this is the Service class  where the methods should be

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository usersRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }


    public List<User> findAll (){
        List<UserEntity> users = usersRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream().map(this::entityToUser).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    public User findUserbyId(int id){
        var userentity = usersRepository.findById(id);
        return userentity.map(this::entityToUser).orElse(null);
    }

    public User update(int id , UserCreateRequest request){
        var userEntityOptional = usersRepository.findById(id);
        if(userEntityOptional.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
       var userEntity = userEntityOptional.get();
        userEntity.setFirstname(request.getFirstname());
        userEntity.setLastname(request.getLastname());
        userEntity.setEmail(request.getEmail());
        usersRepository.save(userEntity);

        return entityToUser(userEntity);
    }

    public boolean deleteById(int id){
        if (!usersRepository.existsById(id)){
            return false;
        }
        usersRepository.existsById(id);
        return true;
    }

    public User create(UserCreateRequest request){
         var userEntity = new UserEntity(request.getFirstname(),request.getLastname(),request.getEmail());
         userEntity = usersRepository.save(userEntity);
        return entityToUser(userEntity);

    }



    public User entityToUser(UserEntity userEntity){
      return new User (
                userEntity.getId(),
                userEntity.getFirstname(),
                userEntity.getLastname(),
                userEntity.getEmail());

    }


}
```

here is the User Controller

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserRestController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> fetchUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findAll()) ;
}
```

I would like to know what do I need exactly to get this function right in an optimal way
what are the necessary steps?

Comment: Before going to improvement first find what problem you are facing with this approach and once you find that you will have clear idea on which side you need to do the improvement From the given piece of code i can suggest you to use @Autowired feature instead of setting it to the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Service
public class UserService {
     //make this Autowired
    @Autowired
    private  UserRepository usersRepository;

    


    public List<User> findAll (){
        List<UserEntity> users = usersRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream().map(this::entityToUser).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    public User findUserbyId(int id){
        var userentity = usersRepository.findById(id);
        return userentity.map(this::entityToUser).orElse(null);
    }

    public User update(int id , UserCreateRequest request){
        var userEntityOptional = usersRepository.findById(id);
        if(userEntityOptional.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
       var userEntity = userEntityOptional.get();
        userEntity.setFirstname(request.getFirstname());
        userEntity.setLastname(request.getLastname());
        userEntity.setEmail(request.getEmail());
        usersRepository.save(userEntity);

        return entityToUser(userEntity);
    }

    public boolean deleteById(int id){
        if (!usersRepository.existsById(id)){
            return false;
        }
        usersRepository.existsById(id);
        return true;
    }

    public User create(UserCreateRequest request){
         var userEntity = new UserEntity(request.getFirstname(),request.getLastname(),request.getEmail());
         userEntity = usersRepository.save(userEntity);
        return entityToUser(userEntity);

    }



    public User entityToUser(UserEntity userEntity){
      return new User (
                userEntity.getId(),
                userEntity.getFirstname(),
                userEntity.getLastname(),
                userEntity.getEmail());

    }


}
```

here is the User Controller

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {
   //make this Autowired
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> fetchUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.findAll()) ;
}
```

Check this to know more about @Autowired https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire